# Minmal API DI reconstructs dependencies even when registered as singleton

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, minimal-apis, message-pipe

Started working on a windows background service in .net that will host a restful service. As I worked on it, it seemed like Minimal APIs were a good fit (it was one of the things I was able to get a working prototype with, I couldn't get other stuff to work). However, I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding something here. When I inspect one of my injected services, I'm noticing that it's being reconstructed each time the endpoint is hit. I didn't think that would happen if I register my services as singletons. Something tells me that due to the nature of Minimal API, there is no way around that. Am I missing something?

I'm using MessagePipe for .net.
`SquareService` implements `IAsyncRequestHandler<LocationByNameRequest, LocationResponse>`

The registration.

```
builder.Services.AddMessagePipe();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SquareService>();
```

The injection.

```
app.MapPut("/pos",
 async (POS station, 
IAsyncRequestHandler<LocationByNameRequest, LocationResponse> handler) => { ...});
```

I made sure that Visual Studio wasn't just randomly ouputing log messages, so I set up a `GUID` in the constructor to verify if the instances might be different (they are).
How else would I host an api in a windows service? Been having problems integrating this, and I think it's because I'm not getting the same references as I was expecting. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with Minimal APIs per se. First of all `builder.Services.AddSingleton<SquareService>();` will register just `SquareService`, not the interfaces it implements, if you resolve `SquareService` in the handler you will get exactly the same instance every time:

```cs
app.MapPut("/pos", async (POS station, SquareService handler) => ...);
```

It seems that `MessagePipe` has it's own custom DI/Lifetime handling. For publishers/subscribers you manipulate the registration type individually by using corresponding interfaces - see [this part of the doc](https://github.com/Cysharp/MessagePipe#isingleton-iscoped):

> `I(Async)Publisher(Subscriber)`'s lifetime is belonging `MessagePipeOptions.InstanceLifetime`. However if declare with `ISingletonPublisher<TMessage>`/`ISingletonSubscriber<TKey, TMessage>`, `ISingletonAsyncPublisher<TMessage>/ISingletonAsyncSubscriber<TKey, TMessage>` then used singleton lifetime. Also `IScopedPublisher<TMessage>/IScopedSubscriber<TKey, TMessage>`, `IScopedAsyncPublisher<TMessage>/IScopedAsyncSubscriber<TKey, TMessage>` uses scoped lifetime.

But for handlers the only option is to set it globally for all the handlers via `MessagePipeOptions` ([docs](https://github.com/Cysharp/MessagePipe#requesthandlerlifetime)):

> Configure `IRequestHandler`/`IAsyncRequestHandler`'s lifetime of DI container. You can choose `Singleton` or `Scoped` or `Transient`. Default is `Scoped`.

```cs
services.AddMessagePipe(options => options.RequestHandlerLifetime = InstanceLifetime.Singleton);
```

Comment: Oh man, I forgot about MessagePipe's option and DI. I had set the options in my prototype but forgot to do it when integrating. Thanks a bunch!